# Why aren't there any jets with horizontal-stabilizer-mounted engines?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, horizontal-stabilizer, engine-placement

Looking at the spectrum of where jet aircraft put their engines, there are examples of almost every place that could conceivably used to carry a jet engine:

- [s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707)[l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737)[u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747)[n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_757)[g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_767) [u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777)[n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner)[d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-8)[e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A300)[r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A310) [t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family)[h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330)[e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A340) [w](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A350_XWB)[i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380)[n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_880)[g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-204)[s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146)
- [buried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Comet) [inside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_C102_Jetliner) [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-104) [wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-124)
- *[on top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-72) [of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-74)* the [wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFW-Fokker_614)
- [on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Aviation_Caravelle) [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_DC-9) [sides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-134) [of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAC_One-Eleven) [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker_F28_Fellowship) [aft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_CRJ200) [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_VC10)[lage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62)
- *[in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_727)* [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-154) [aft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Siddeley_Trident) [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_L-1011_TriStar)[lage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-42)
- [on/in the vertical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_DC-10) [stabilizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_MD-11)

Notably absent, however, are jets with engines having anything to do with the horizontal stabilizer.

Why aren't there any jets with engines mounted on/in their horizontal stabilizer?

Comment: Related: [Would there be any benefit in placing the aircraft engines on the elevator (end-tips)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30665/1696)

Comment: Because we want the stabilizer to have smooth air, hence away from anything, including the engine.

Comment: I think some fighter jets like the F-14 would come pretty close.  But in general, it's just a matter of structural strength: you'd have to make the stabilizer much stronger to handle the thrust of the engine.

Comment: Your linking game is *en pointe*. Especially the first example!

Comment: It may not be what you are looking for, but engines are placed on the stabilizing part of concorde's delta wing.

Comment: With the DC-10/MD-11, the engine isn't IN the vertical stabilizer.  Rather, the stabilizer is mounted on top of the engine.  We could probably find a lot of single-engine jets with the same basic design, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter

Comment: @jamesqf: Hence the "on/" part of that example.  Besides, the long intake _is_ mounted in the stabilizer, with essentially all the same aerodynamic effects that would result from the engine itself being in the stabilizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two configurations I can think of:

#### The jet mounted on the horizontal stabilizer (above, below, at the tip):

Unlike the vertical stabilizer, the horizontal stabilizer is trimmable ([THS](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Trimmable_Horizontal_Stabiliser)), so all of the engine connections (fuel, hydraulic, pneumatic) will need to be made flexible and/or pivotable, which results in added complexity and points of failure. And, the longer lateral placement of the engines will considerably increase the weight; a standard THS mounting (just two points for pivoting) is not built for transferring the thrust to the airframe. This also impacts the loading flexibility; a very tail heavy plane can't have as many passengers in the back without adding a forward ballast, further increasing the weight.

#### The jet mounted at the root and doesn't move with the THS:

While certainly achievable, like the L-1011's number two engine wrt the vertical stabilizer, the issue here is not why aren't the jet engines there, it's why the THS is **not** there.

The horizontal stabilizer of a plane like the DC-9 (and its extended family) is purposefully placed above the tail, creating a T-tail. With the tail swept back, the top of it is farther from the plane's center of gravity, giving the THS a [bigger moment arm](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17221/14897), and in turn allowing a smaller THS, and the other benefit that comes out of that is the [end-plate effect of the T-tail](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45702/14897), which also permits a shorter fin for the same control authority.

You'll also notice buried engines are of the older small-diameter type, except for large planes like the L-1011, but still that makes maintenance access a lot harder, than an exposed engine.

Comment: If the engine is mounted on the THS, wouldn't the tilted thrust vector create a pitching moment in the _same_ direction as the intended trim, allowing the amount of THS movement for a given trim operation to be reduced?

Comment: @Vikki: I think you're right, I'll revise it, thanks.

Comment: "a very tail heavy plane can't have as many passengers in the back without adding a forward ballast, further increasing the weight" A tail-heavy plane would compensate by having more fuselage ahead of the wings, just like today's tail-heavy planes do.  Additionally, would the stabilizer's attachment points really have to be reinforced by _that_ much to carry the engines' thrust?  They already have to be pretty beefy to handle the huge amounts of downwards lift the stabilizer can generate.

Comment: @Vikki: today's examples aren't *that* tail heavy, so you would need *even* longer fuselages that will mess with the [fineness ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fineness_ratio); today's examples [need ballast](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Lufthansa-Cargo/McDonnell-Douglas-MD-11F/2151105) when light, and yes they're definitely not built to withstand *and transfer* some 100 kN longitudinally, but if you want to unaccept, feel free.